how to use gitlab api for a project hosted on gitlab cloud
I recently migrated my project instance to gitlab cloud.
The project pipelines url was in this form before: https://gitlab.example-domain.de/example-platform/example-project/-/pipelines?page=1&scope=all&ref=master
I was using
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example-domain.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/46"

command to fetch a pipeline.
Now, moving to cloud, the url for my pipelines look like this:
https://gitlab.com/example-domain/example-groupname/example-projectname/-/pipelines
I like to understand which command to use Gitlab pipelines api with the current setup of my project. I tried several but they did not work.
